# How to align this menu at the center of the web page?

Tags: css

How to align this menu at the center of the web page?
How to align this menu at the center of the web page? Will appreciate if this code could be written even better than what it appears now. Thanks in advance.

edit: also how can I make the a:hover in green to full width as yellow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>.</title>


<style>
#logo {font-family:arial; color:teal;text-align:center;}


ul{margin:0; padding:0;}
li{list-style:none;padding:20px; margin:2px;width:150px;background-color:yellow;margin:10px; text-   align:center;}
a {text-decoration:none;font-family:arial;font-weight:bold;padding:20px;color:teal;}

.menu li a:hover {background-color:green;color:white  !important;}
.menu li a:visited {color:teal;}
```

```
<body>
<h1 id="logo"> TEXT </h1>

<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li> <a href="#text1"> Text1 </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#text2"> Text2 </a> </li>
<li> <a href="#text3"> Text3 </a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `ul {margin:0 auto;}` ?

Comment: nope. not working. It moves few margins to the right but not at the center.

Answer (score 0):

Changes you need to make to your code:

1. Add a `width` to `ul` and apply `margin: 0 auto` to center it horizontally on the webpage.
2. Apply the `:hover` state to `li`, to change the entire `background-color` of the `li`.
3. Change `margin: 10px` to `margin-top: 10px` in `li`.
4. Add `cursor: pointer` to `li:hover` to change the cursor on hover.

```css
#logo {
  font-family: arial;
  color: teal;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 190px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: teal;
}
.menu li:hover {
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.menu li:hover a {
  color: white;
}
.menu li a:visited {
  color: teal;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="logo"> TEXT </h1>

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#text1"> Text1 </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#text2"> Text2 </a> 
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#text3"> Text3 </a> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: but I want white text when hovered- color: white !important;

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello you can use this code:

.menu{
    text-align: center;
}
.menu ul{
  display: inline-block;
}

to align your menu to center
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu{ 
    position:relative; 
    top:20px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

You can Adjust the position by changing left and top values.To move position in opposite direction,make the values negative

```
.menu{ 
    position:relative; 
    top:-20px;
    left:-200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 .menu{
        text-align: center;
    }
    ul{
       display: inline-block;
    }
    li:hover{
       background-color: green;
    }
    li:hover a{
       color: white;
    }
```